# How to copy and paste a file?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want copy and paste a file. The name of the file is `mkoctfile.m`.
The path of this file is:

`/usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/miscellaneous/mkoctfile.m`

I want to paste it to the following path

`/usr/bin/mkoctfile-3.2.4`

I have made the directory by using following commands:

`sudo su`
`mkdir -p /usr/bin/mkoctfile-3.2.4`

but I don't know how to copy and paste `mkoctfile.m` in this path.

Please tell me what command I have to use.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the `cp` command to copy a file, the syntax goes `cp sourcefile destinationfile`.
Use the `mv` command to move the file, basically cut and paste it somewhere else.

The exact syntax you would use for your example is:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/octave/3.2.4/m/miscellaneous/mkoctfile.m /usr/bin/mkoctfile-3.2.4
```

For more information on the `cp` or `mv` commands you can run:

```
man cp
```

or

```
man mv
```

To view the manual pages

Comment: thanks! but typing out the full file path is difficult. is there a better way?

Comment: To @BKSurgeon, I would suggest to use the tab key to see the paths/directories available, or type ls to see them all at once printed.

Comment: I think it is better to use `cp -a` than just `cp`, if you want to have the same affect as when copy-pasting in desktop GUI.

Answer (score 3):

You can cut, copy, and paste in CLI intuitively like the way you usually did in the GUI, like so:

- `cd` to the folder containing files you want to copy or cut.
- `copy file1 file2 folder1 folder2` or `cut file1 folder1`
- close the current terminal.
- open another terminal.
- `cd` to the folder where you want to paste them.
- `paste`

To be able to do so, make sure you have installed `xclip` and `realpath`. Then, append these functions to the end of your *~/.bashrc* file:

```bash
copy() {
    # if the number of arguments equals 0
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        # if there are no arguments, save the folder you are currently in to the clipboard
        pwd | xclip
    else
        # save the number of argument/path to `~/.numToCopy` file.
        echo $# > ~/.numToCopy

        # save all paths to clipboard
        # https://stackoverflow.com/q/5265702/9157799#comment128297633_5265775
        realpath -s "$@" | xclip
    fi

    # mark that you want to do a copy operation
    echo "copy" > ~/.copyOrCut
}

cut() {
    # use the previous function to save the paths to clipboard
    copy "$@"

    # but mark it as a cut operation
    echo "cut" > ~/.copyOrCut
}

paste() {
    # for every path
    for ((i=1; i <= $(cat ~/.numToCopy); i++))
    do
        # get the nth path
        pathToCopy="$(xclip -o | head -$i | tail -1)"

        if [ -d "$pathToCopy" ] # If it's a directory
        then
            cp -r "$pathToCopy" .
        else
            cp "$pathToCopy" .
        fi

        # if it was marked as a cut operation
        if [ $(cat ~/.copyOrCut) = "cut" ]
        then
            # delete the original file
            rm -r "$pathToCopy"
        fi
    done
}
```

If you don't know what *.bashrc* file is and never modify it before, just open the file explorer, go to Home, press Ctrl+H (show hidden files), search for *.bashrc* and open it with a text editor like gedit.

**Note**

By using the above script, you are overriding the default functionality of these commands:

- `copy` is a reserved PostgreSQL command.
- `cut` and `paste` are reserved Linux command.

If you use one of those commands default functionality, just modify the script function names accordingly. For example, use `p` instead of `paste`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to that directory from where you want to copy file i.e /usr/bin/octave/3.2.4/m/miscellaneous

```
cd /usr/bin/octave/3.2.4/m/miscellaneous
```

Then type

```
`cp mkoctfile.m ../../../mkoctfile-3.2.4`
```

`../../../` means you are going backward to bin folder and type whatever directory in which you want to copy your file.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting solution based on @M Imam Pratama's idea (Copy / Cut now and paste later).

Consider using [xclip-copyfile, xclip-cutfile and xclip-pastefile](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/xclip-copyfile.1.html).

```
$ xclip-copyfile file1
$ xclip-cutfile file1
$ xclip-pastefile file1
```

You can also copy an entire tree structure.

**WARNING:** `xclip-cutfile` immediately remove the file, does not wait until you paste it.